# Is highest refresh rate and color depth causes any issues?

Tags: display, refresh-rate

Is highest refresh rate i.e. `240Hz` makes CPU slow?
Is highest color depth i.e. `62bit` makes CPU slow?
Is highest refresh rate too causes eye strain?

Comment: There is no way your system is actually set to use a 1 Hz refresh rate. That would mean that the screen is only updated once per second. A quick test should be enough to tell you that this is not the case: move the mouse around. More likely, this is just an inane way of expressing "no value found".

Comment: 1 hz wouldn't cause any strain, it would be a slideshow tho ;p

Comment: I think monitor is overwriting the configurations.

Answer (score 1):

### A minimum of 70Hz is recommended to help prevent eye strain, and many experts believe 80Hz and above is best.

[reference](http://lookup.computerlanguage.com/host_app/search?cid=C999999&def=766572746963616c207363616e206672657175656e6379.htm)

What are the advantages of having a higher color depth?

With higher color depth, you get more visually appealing features like gradients and transparencies. Many people also report the picture being brighter and being less of a strain on their eyes when running at a higher color depth.

What are the disadvantages of having a higher color depth?

As mentioned above, with a higher color depth it requires more system resources that make the computer work more. If your computer is running low on memory, it may slow down the system. Also, with gaming a higher color depth may decrease your FPS depending on your video card and the game you are playing.
[reference](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001557.htm)

[image]
[Image reference](http://lookup.computerlanguage.com/host_app/search?cid=C999999&def=626974206465707468.htm)